# JavaFX 2: Making a ScrollPane automatically scroll to the edge after adding content

Tags: java, javafx-2, scrollpane

Using JavaFX 2, I have a basic example of a `ScrollPane` that contains an `HBox` of `Label`s.  I want to be able to add a `Label` to the `HBox`, and simultaneously scroll to the right edge of the `ScrollPane` so that the newly added `Label` is visible.  My current method uses the `setHvalue()` to set the scroll position and `getHmax()` to get the maximum scrolling distance allowed.

The problem is that when I set the scroll position using `getHmax()`, it is as if the just-added `Label` is not computed in the `ScrollPanel`'s scroll width.  Is there a way that I can update this inner width before trying `setHvalue`?

Please see this simple example code which exhibits the issue.

In particular, please notice the `addChatItem(String item)` method, which contains the logic for scrolling to the edge of the `ScrollPane`.

```
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.text.Font;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class ScrollPaneTest extends Application {   
        static int defaultFontSize = 30;

        ScrollPaneTest scrollPaneTest = this;

        ScrollPane chatBoxScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        HBox chatBox = new HBox();
        Chatter chatter = new Chatter();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);//default
        }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws Exception {
            super.stop();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();       

            StackPane chatBoxStackPane = new StackPane();

            chatBoxScrollPane.setContent(chatBox);
            //chatBoxScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
            chatBoxScrollPane.setMaxHeight(50);

            chatBoxStackPane.getChildren().add(chatBoxScrollPane);

            borderPane.setCenter(chatBoxStackPane);


            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 800, 600);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Scroll Demo");
            primaryStage.show(); 


            new Thread("mainGameControlThread") {
                public void run() {
                    chatter.chatLoop(scrollPaneTest);
                }
            }.start();
        }

        public void addChatItem(String chatString) {
            Label title = new Label(chatString);        
            title.setFont(new Font("Verdana", defaultFontSize));

            chatBox.getChildren().add(title);

            chatBoxScrollPane.setHvalue(chatBoxScrollPane.getHmax());
        }

        class Chatter {
            public void chatLoop(final ScrollPaneTest test) {

                Timer closingCeremonyTimer = new Timer();
                closingCeremonyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run() {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override 
                            public void run() {
                                test.addChatItem("Hello World. ");
                            }
                        });
                        chatLoop(test);
                    }
                }, (long) (0.5*1000));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an image of issue, notice how the `ScrollPane` has not scrolled to the right edge.

[image]

***Edit:***

I've come up with a workaround but it is very far from ideal.  My solution is to start a timer which will use `setHvalue()` after enough time has passed for the `ScrollPane` to discover the true width of its content.  my `addChatItem()` method now looks like this:

```
public void addChatItem(String chatString) {
    Label title = new Label(chatString);        
    title.setFont(new Font("Verdana", defaultFontSize));

    chatBox.getChildren().add(title);

    Timer closingCeremonyTimer = new Timer();       
    closingCeremonyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            chatBoxScrollPane.setHvalue(chatBoxScrollPane.getHmax());
        }
    }, (long) 50);
}
```

Unfortunately, the number 50 in that method needs to be greater than the time that it takes the `ScrollPane` to update its inner content's width, and that seems to be far from guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can bind to Hbox widthproperty chnages .

**Sample Code :**

```
   //in start method add this code
    DoubleProperty wProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    wProperty.bind(chatBox.widthProperty()); // bind to Hbox width chnages
    wProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
           //when ever Hbox width chnages set ScrollPane Hvalue
         chatBoxScrollPane.setHvalue(chatBoxScrollPane.getHmax()); 
        }
    }) ;
```

and

```
 // remove below line from your addChatItem() method   
 chatBoxScrollPane.setHvalue(chatBoxScrollPane.getHmax());
```

Result :yes added numbering for fun ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to enclose a HBox called labels inside a ScrollPane called msgs and here is the way I handled autoscroll.

NOTE: The changeListener added to labels HBox is implemented via Lambda syntax(available in JDK8)

```
labels.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) ->{
        msgs.setVvalue(((Double) newVal).doubleValue());
    });
```