# In JavaFX how can I programmatically scroll a Scrollpane to the bottom?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have been working on a small chat client for me and some friends, teaching myself Java and JFX 8 on the side. Unfortunately, for some reason I am unable to programmatically scroll to the bottom of a ScrollPane where the chat messages are.

I have a method I simply called scrollToBottom() which executes the following code:

```
public void scrollToBottom() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> this.getChatView().vvalueProperty().setValue(1.0));
}
```

I have a button that works using this method for scrolling to the bottom, but any other programmatical approach (even firing the button from other methods) does not correctly update the scrollbar of the scrollpane. However, when I call getVvalue() on the scrollpane after supposedly scrolling, it returns the correct value that I'm trying to get it to scroll through. The scrollpane is just not scrolling to the supposed value.

Below I have the only really relevant class in the application - the ChatBox type is just an extension of VBox that only uses an extended type of Text.

```
public class MainScreenController {

    //Lists

    //Buttons
    private Button logoutButton;
    private Button btn1 = new Button("Test Button");
    private Button scrollButton = new Button("Scroll Button");

    //Numbers

    //Booleans
    private boolean isHosting;

    //Strings
    private String username = "";

    //Scene
    private Stage window;
    private GridPane layout = new GridPane();

    //Other Objects
    private TextArea chatField = new TextArea();
    private Label usernameLabel;
    private TextArea usersArea = new TextArea("Connected users: ");
    private VBox firstColumn = new VBox(10);
    private VBox secondColumn = new VBox(10);
    private ImageView mediaColumn = new ImageView();
    private Server server = new Server();
    private Client client = new Client();
    private TextField dlField = new TextField();
    private AudioHandler audioHandler = new AudioHandler();
    private ChatBox chatBox = new ChatBox();
    private ScrollPane chatView = new ScrollPane(this.chatBox);
    private HBox buttonBox = new HBox(10);

    private void initChatView() {

        this.getChatView().setMinSize(500, 500);
        this.getChatView().setPrefSize(500, 500);
        this.getChatView().setMaxSize(500, 500);
        this.getChatView().setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent; -fx-background-color: gainsboro");
        this.chatView.hbarPolicyProperty().set(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        this.chatView.vbarPolicyProperty().set(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        /*this.chatView.vvalueProperty().addListener(e -> {
              if(this.chatView.getVvalue() != 1) {
                  System.out.println("Pre: " + this.chatView.getVvalue());
                  this.chatView.vvalueProperty().set(1);
                  System.out.println("Post: " + this.chatView.getVvalue());
                }
        });*/

        this.scrollButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            scrollToBottom();
        });

    }

    private void initSecondColumn() {

        this.secondColumn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gainsboro");
        this.secondColumn.setPrefSize(525, 550);
        this.secondColumn.setMinSize(450, 550);
        this.secondColumn.setMaxSize(525, 550);

        Button dlButton = new Button("Download link:");
        dlButton.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent");
        dlButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (!this.dlField.getText().equals(null) || !this.dlField.getText().equals(null)) {
                try {
                    FileHandler.downloadFile(this.window, this.dlField.getText());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.dlField.clear();
            }
        });
        this.dlField.setPrefSize(450, 20);
        this.dlField.setMinSize(450, 20);
        this.dlField.setMaxSize(450, 20);

        this.mediaColumn.setFitHeight(475);
        this.mediaColumn.setPreserveRatio(true);
        this.mediaColumn.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
        this.mediaColumn.prefWidth(450);
        this.mediaColumn.prefHeight(475);
        this.mediaColumn.minWidth(450);
        this.mediaColumn.minHeight(475);
        this.mediaColumn.maxWidth(450);
        this.mediaColumn.maxHeight(475);
        this.secondColumn.getChildren().addAll(dlButton, this.dlField, mediaColumn);

    }

    private void initUsersArea() {

        this.usersArea.setPrefSize(500, 75);
        this.usersArea.setMinSize(500, 75);
        this.usersArea.setMaxSize(500, 75);
        this.usersArea.setEditable(false);
        this.usersArea.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent; -fx-background-color: gainsboro");

    }

    public void scrollToBottom() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.getChatView().vvalueProperty().setValue(1.0));
        System.out.println(this.chatView.getVvalue());
    }

    public MainScreenController(GridPane layout, Stage window, Scene currentScene, Scene nextScene, WindowController windowController) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

        new File(FileHandler.downloadsPath).mkdirs();
        this.layout = layout;
        this.window = window;
        this.initChatView();
        FileHandler.readLog(this.getChatBox());

    }

    private void initUsernameLabel() {

        this.usernameLabel = new Label();
        this.usernameLabel.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: silver; -fx-focus-color: transparent");
        this.usernameLabel.setText(" Logged in as ");
        this.usernameLabel.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

    }

    private void initLayout() {

        this.layout.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        this.layout.setVgap(10);
        this.layout.setHgap(10);
        this.layout.getChildren().addAll(this.firstColumn, this.secondColumn);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(this.firstColumn, 0);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(this.secondColumn, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(secondColumn, VPos.BOTTOM);
        this.buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(this.logoutButton, this.scrollButton);
        this.firstColumn.getChildren().addAll(this.buttonBox, this.usernameLabel, this.usersArea, this.chatView, this.getChatField());

    }

    public void initBtn1() {
        btn1.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent");
        GridPane.setConstraints(btn1, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(btn1, VPos.BASELINE);
        this.layout.getChildren().add(btn1);
        btn1.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, e -> {
            boolean b = false;
            if (!b) {
                audioHandler.startRecording();
                b = !b;
            } else if (b) {
                audioHandler.stopRecording();
                b = !b;
            }
        });
    }

    public void addMessage(String msg, String color) {

        FileHandler.writeToChatLog(msg);

        if (!msg.startsWith("*!") && !msg.startsWith("/")) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                this.getChatBox().addText(new ChatText(msg, color));
                this.scrollButton.arm();
                this.scrollButton.fire();
            });
        }

    }

    private void initChatField() {

        this.getChatField().setPrefSize(500, 10);
        this.getChatField().setMaxHeight(10);
        this.getChatField().autosize();
        this.getChatField().setWrapText(true);
        this.getChatField().addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, key -> {
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                key.consume();
                if (this.getChatField().getText().startsWith("/")) {
                    CommandParser.parse(this.getChatField().getText(), this);
                } else {
                    try {
                        this.getClient().getClientSendingData().writeUTF(this.getChatField().getText().trim());
                        this.getChatField().clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this.getChatField().setStyle("-fx-background-color: gainsboro");

    }

    private void initLogoutButton() {

        this.logoutButton = new Button();
        this.logoutButton.setText("Log out");
        this.logoutButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            try {
                this.client.getClientSendingData().writeUTF("*![System] " + SystemInfo.getDate() + ": " + this.client.getClientName() + " has disconnected.");
                System.out.println("Logging out.");
                window.close();
                new ChatClient().start(new Stage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        this.logoutButton.setStyle("-fx-focus-color: transparent");

    }

    public void initMainScreen() {

        initUsernameLabel();
        initLogoutButton();
        initChatField();
        initLayout();
        initUsersArea();
        initBtn1();
        initSecondColumn();

    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public Label getUsernameLabel() {
        return this.usernameLabel;
    }

    public GridPane getLayout() {
        return this.layout;
    }

    public void setIsHosting(boolean b) {
        this.isHosting = b;
    }

    public boolean getIsHosting() {
        return this.isHosting;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return this.server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server hostServer) {
        this.server = hostServer;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public ScrollPane getChatView() {
        return chatView;
    }

    public void setChatView(ScrollPane chatView) {
        this.chatView = chatView;
    }

    public TextArea getChatField() {
        return chatField;
    }

    public void setChatField(TextArea chatField) {
        this.chatField = chatField;
    }

    public TextArea getUsersArea() {
        return this.usersArea;
    }

    public ChatBox getChatBox() {
        return chatBox;
    }

    public void setChatBox(ChatBox chatBox) {
        this.chatBox = chatBox;
    }

}
```

And if you have any other general suggestions (I'm just now learning Java) all tips are welcome. :) 
Thanks!

Comment: [Maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333396/javafx-make-scrollpane-scroll-automatically) or [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992731/javafx-2-making-a-scrollpane-automatically-scroll-to-the-edge-after-adding-cont) or [maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156896/javafx-auto-scroll-down-scrollpane) or even [maybe](http://javafx-demos.googlecode.com/svn-history/r77/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/java/com/ezest/javafx/demogallery/internet/ScrollPaneScrollToEnd.java)...

Comment: @MadProgrammer None of the above seemed to work - I did try them. Unfortunately the issue seems not to be that I can't scroll at all, but that for some reason I don't understand scrolling only works in some cases.

Comment: if you show code, please make sure it's a SSCCE - all the "just" in your description of the differences to plain fx may make all the difference between working or not :-) In you case, that could be a short example that _just_ contains a plain textArea (maybe in a vbox) with initial content as needed and  a button that triggers the scroll.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found that the problem was due to multithreading. For anyone who is interested, try adding a very small Thread.sleep() on the thread executing the scrollToBottom() call; I went with 10 ms as the lowest that seemed to work. Thanks to anyone who tried to help.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` hacks like this to get around threading related issues are almost always the wrong solution, even if it seems to work.

Comment: @jewelsea What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: I suggest you do as kleopatra suggested and place an SSCCE ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in stackoverflow terms) in your question; i.e. *minimal*, compilable, executable code that replicates only your issue and nothing else.  Then it would be simpler for somebody to understand what you are trying to do, what your issue is and to create an answer which can suggest a reasonable alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

What I do to scroll the text in a TextArea to the bottom is, to set the caret in the text to the end of the text, like:

```
textArea.positionCaret(textArea.getText().length());
```

In fact, to make sure that the text in the TextArea doesn't scroll horizontally to the left (e.g. when the last line in the TextArea is very long), I set the caret right behind the last "\n" in the text, like this:

```
String content = textArea.getText();
int indexOfLastLineFeed = content.lastIndexOf("\n");
if (indexOfLastLineFeed == -1)
    textArea.positionCaret(content.length());
else
    textArea.positionCaret(Math.min(indexOfLastLineFeed + 1, content.length()));
```

Answer (score 2):

That bug also happened to me while Imusing ScrollPane with MasonryPane (from JFoenix). The solution I found is by calling layout() method of the scrollpane and its content. The hierarchy: ScrollPane -> MasonryPane`

```
masonryPane.getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) c -> {
            masonryPane.layout();
            scrollPane.layout();
            scrollPane.setVvalue(1.0f);
        });
```